# Is it okay to respond "Amein" to a gibberish prayer made in jest?

Tags: halacha, prayer-book, chazzan-prayer-leader, amen

As the title says, is it permissible to respond "Amein" and "B'rik Hu"to a Kaddish/Chatzi Kaddish prayer made in gibberish, with words like "Blah blah blah" thrown in for jest? Or should one stay silent in such cases?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. One cannot play when praying and mess up the actual service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shulchan Aruch ([OC 215:4](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1045)) writes:

> כל המברך ברבה שאינה צריבה הרי זה נושא שם שמים לשוא והרי הוא כנשבע לשוא
>    **ואסור לענות אחריו אמן**
>
> Anyone who says a blessing that is not necessary is mentioning Hashem's name in vain and is like swearing falsely, **and it is forbidden to answer *Amen* after it**.

In addition, the Taz ([OC 560:5](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2923)) writes that it is a great sin to sing Kaddish at a meal, and all the more so to make a joke out of *pesukim* or holy words.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not clear, but:

- If it's an actual prayer, then added in "sounds" are acceptable. It's not unusual for a Chazzan to add in *la-lala-la* or similar - so as to stretch the words to the tune. Answering Amein is correct.
- If it's a parody that simply sounds like a prayer then there's a problem answering Amein (called an *orphaned Amein* - one without a prayer preceding it). Depending on circumstances it may also be in bad taste. (Apparently, nothing is in bad taste on Purim, according to some.)

Comment: "Apparently, nothing is in bad taste on Purim, according to some" Can you give a source for this?

Comment: @Ploni - that was said "tongue in cheek" based on other people's (mis)behavior on Purim.